# Recording quality has significant noise

Tags: audio, recording, noise, vocals, laptop

I have a Foucsrite scarlet solo and a bheringer C-1 microphone. I'm recording with a Acer laptop (which has a i5 cpu) which should be more than capable to power this setup. The problem is the quality of the recording, right now the audio that I'm getting has a significant amount of noise. I'm using Audacity. I've researched for a solution but still haven't found it. I'm starting to think maybe the scarlet solo itself is the cause, because I was recording on a older HP laptop with a first generation i3. At first the recordings were crystal clear however one day I go to record and the audio had the same white noise as the Acer however the quality was still better than the Acer.

Comment: provide a sample of the noise that's about 20-30 seconds long so we can evaluate the type of noise and (if possible) will tell you how to get rid of it it

Answer (score 2):

There are a dozen different things that could be called "noise". Unless we can identify exactly what kind of "noise" you are talking about, we probably can't help you much.  Take 30 seconds of representative sample (including both normal-level sound, including adequate sample of the noise.  Post it somewhere online where we can hear it.

Can we assume that when you changed the gear you are working with, you went back through and adjusted all the levels properly ("gain-staging").

It is difficult to imagine how the computer itself could cause such a dramatic difference in "noise". Is it acoustic noise from the computer fan or something?